# Convert Procedural to Object Oriented: Python3.4

Tags: python, class, oop

In the interest of being more "pythonic" (and being more modular), I want to convert my procedural code to a `Class`.  The object of interest here is the idea of a marriage of `husband` and `wife`, referred to here as `lastname`, with some shared and some unique attributes among each spouse.  These attributes are being filled in from a file into a generator object via `yield`.

Part of me wants to perform these two parsing functions `get_husband` and `get_wife` (and maybe the final zip function) as a Class function that still uses an iterator object to fill in the attributes of `marriage.firstname`, `marriage.husbandscore`, `marriage.wifescore`, etc.  I would then create methods that would perform further analysis on the information from each `marriage` object as it is spit out from the generator.

But part of me is unsure whether the parsing definitions are best kept as methods, since I would be returning `self` which is not the generator that I need for my downstream work...

```
from itertools import izip

def get_husband(husbandfile):
    lastname, firstname, husbandscore = '', '', ''
    for line in husbandfile.readlines():
        # Parse files to fill out the names, wifescores in wifefile
        yield name, husbandscore

def get_wife(wifefile):
    lastname, firstname, wifescore = '', '',''
    for line in wifefile.readlines():
        # Parse files to fill out the names, wifescores in wifefile
        yield name, wifescore

def make_family(husbandfile, wifefile):
    for husband, wife in izip(get_husband(husbandfile), get_wife(wifefile)):
        if husband[0] == wife[0]:
            lastname = husband[0]
            parentscore = husband[1] + wife[0]

            yield lastname, parentscore
        else:
            raise Exception("These two aren't married
```

What do you suppose is the best way to factor this as a class so I can be like: `min_score = marriage.parentscore.min()`

Comment: This code is pretty "Pythonic". Converting to OOP for no clear reason, however, is not.